# Monitoring ContentManagerKernel fails in SDL Web 8.5

Tags: web8.5, content-manager, monitoring

I have enabled monitoring in SDL Web 8.5 by commenting out the services I would like to monitor. This all works fine except for the ContentManagerKernel. If I enable this one I get the following error:

```
03-15 15:24:53,680 INFO  AbstractHTTPHealthMonitor - TMA-PO-10001 Service ContentManagerKernel - Health check failed. Status: HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error
```

This element is configured as follows:

```
<XmlHttpServiceHealthMonitor ServiceType="ContentManagerKernel" PollInterval="10m" TimeoutInterval="30s">
          <Request URL="http://localhost/webservices/CoreService2012.svc/basicHttp" SOAPAction="http://www.sdl.com/ContentManager/CoreService/2012/ICoreService/GetCurrentUser"/>
          <Authentication Scheme="NTLM" Domain="RWSTRID323" Username="MTSUser" Password="Tr1d10n2018"/>
    </XmlHttpServiceHealthMonitor>
```

Any ideas how to resolve this?

Answer (score 1):

If indeed 8.5, try using the latest endpoint in the `URL` attribute of the `Request` node. You will most likely have to update the `SOAPAction` as well to reflect this change.